# Dependecy specified in Compile doesn't reflect for Runtime in Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, gradlew

I am depending on apache commons lang jar. In Compile i added the following, now compilation succeeds but during runtime, I get classNoFound exception

```
compile(
'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.1.0',
)
```

If i don't specify the above, even compilation fails. Now only runtime I get the error. Please help.

As I understand, If you specify for compile, it is visible for runtime as well. 
Please help.

Comment: Compile dependencies will be available at runtime, unless your build does something very custom. Perhaps the problem is somewhere else. In any case, you'd have to provide (much) more information.

Comment: True, Our build system had some customizations for runtime, hence the issue. Thank @PeterNiederwieser